# How to select custom data and data from table in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got this code here:

```
select 
    'Hussain' as name

select
    nameColumn as name
from
    nameTable
```

When I run this code, it only returns 'Hussain' as name and ignores the second statement.

How do I select both?

Comment: Hint:  `UNION ALL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use union all

```
  select 
        'Hussain' as name
    union all
    select
        nameColumn as name
    from
        nameTable
```

Answer (score 0):

If 'Hussain' is already present in your nameTable then to avoid duplicasy use following query.

```
SELECT name
FROM
     (
         SELECT 'Hussain' AS name
         UNION
         SELECT nameColumn AS name
         FROM nameTable
      )
```